# Automate Jenkins Keycloak plugin with groovy script

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, keycloak, jenkins-groovy

i try to 100% automating the deployment of Jenkins with Keycloak plugin with Docker-compose. The objectiv is that we do not want to do anything but run a single command.

To automate Jenkins, I tried to use the Jenkins API but the Groovy script seems to be the best and easiest solution. The problem is that I am not a developper ...

I try something like this, but it's failed at Keycloak conf :

```
Failed to run script file:/var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/init.groovy groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.jenkinsci.plugins.KeycloakSecurityRealm(java.lang.Boolean)
```

---

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.*

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def env = System.getenv()

def hudsonRealm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)
String password = env.JENKINS_PASSWORD
hudsonRealm.createAccount("admin", password)
instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonRealm)
instance.save()

def keycloak_realm = new KeycloakSecurityRealm(true)
instance.setSecurityRealm(keycloak_realm)

instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(new FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy())

instance.save()
```

In the end, i want to

- create an admin user
- configure the Keycloak plugin
- set the users autorisations.

Thanks you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

A possibly outdated issue, but I would like to share that I also had problems using Groovy scripts in the init.groovy.d to maintain the configurations in Jenkins, including Keycloak configurations. And the best way to solve it was through a declarative model using the [Jenkins Configuration as Code (JCasC)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin) plugin.

Examples:

*Keycloak*

```
jenkins:
  securityRealm: keycloak

unclassified:
  keycloakSecurityRealm:
    keycloakJson: |-
      {
        "realm": "my-realm",
        "auth-server-url": "https://my-keycloak-url/auth",
        "ssl-required": "all",
        "resource": "jenkins",
        "public-client": true,
        "confidential-port": 0
      }
```

source: https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/tree/master/demos/keycloak

*Credentials*

```
credentials:
  system:
    domainCredentials:
      - domain:
          name: "test.com"
          description: "test.com domain"
          specifications:
            - hostnameSpecification:
                includes: "*.test.com"
        credentials:
          - usernamePassword:
              scope: SYSTEM
              id: sudo_password
              username: root
              password: ${SUDO_PASSWORD}
```

source: https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/tree/master/demos/credentials

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.security.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.KeycloakSecurityRealm

Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.get()

def desc = jenkins.getDescriptor("org.jenkinsci.plugins.KeycloakSecurityRealm")
// JSON based on the keycloak configuration
desc.setKeycloakJson(    "{\n" +
            "  \"realm\": \"myRealm\",\n" +
            "  \"auth-server-url\": \"https://keycloak/auth/\",\n" +
            "  \"ssl-required\": \"external\",\n" +
            "  \"resource\": \"jenkins\",\n" +
            "  \"public-client\": true,\n" +
            "  \"confidential-port\": 0\n" +
            "}")
desc.save()
jenkins.setSecurityRealm(new KeycloakSecurityRealm())

def strategy = new FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy()
strategy.setAllowAnonymousRead(false)
jenkins.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)
jenkins.save()
```